# Which of the following is a better pattern for writing a "fetch" custom hook in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a written a custom hook `useContent` to fetch local assets.
This is how I use the hook in one of the components.

```js
const {
    isLoaded: contentLoaded,
    content: content,
    error: contentLoadingError,
  } = useContent('assets/readme.md');
```

I can write the hook in two ways.
The first approach results in two react renders, but the second one causes only one render.

I feel that the second approach is better. Is this correct ? Or are there any caveats when using the second approach?

**Custom Hook Approach 1**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useContent =(path) => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(path)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((payload) => {
        setContent(payload);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return {
    isLoaded,
    content,
    error
  };
}

export default useContent;
```

**Custom Hook Approach 2**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useContent =(path) => {
  const initialState = {
    isLoaded: false,
    content: null,
    error: null
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(path)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((payload) => {
        setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          content: payload,
          error: null
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          content: null,
          error: err
        });
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return {
    isLoaded: state.isLoaded,
    content: state.content,
    error: state.error
  };
}

export default useContent;
```

Comment: The boundaries between different stack exchange sites are fuzzy and hard to get right, but I sometimes like asking these kinds of questions on the codereview stack exchange - check it out, there's some cool stuff there similar to your question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The first approach shouldn't actually cause 2 rerenders. React doesn't rerender as soon as you call a setState function, it defers it for a little bet and aggregates the setStates together. So, performance shouldn't be an issue.

I generally prefer splitting apart values into separate useState()s like you did in your first example - it gives you more flexibility to update bits of state independently. However, that's certainly not a hard rule, and there's an elegance to your second example. So, in this specific case, the second could be a good choice here.

What makes your situation here different from many others is that your bits of state are all related. For example, it would be an invalid state if content was set, but loaded was not true. It's because of this intertwined nature that lumping this state into one object is useful - it allows updates to this state to happen in one atomic action, not multiple, separate setStates. This reduces the chance of your hook ending up in an invalid state.

Comment: “bits of state are all related” translates to “useReducer”